# Who consumes more memory, ArrayList or HashSet / LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, collections

I have a very huge collection, so even relatively small memory difference can make difference.

Or the difference is minimal?

Does memory consumtion growth differently when we add more elements?

I believe that LinkedHashSet eats more memory per N elements than HashSet (to store linked-list links), but I cannot compare ArrayList to HashSet.

Comment: ArrayList typically uses 4-8 bytes per reference, HashSet typically uses ~32 bytes. Unless you have hundreds of millions of values, it might not make as much difference as you think.

Comment: There are quite a few collection libraries that aim to be more memory efficient than standard java collection implementations, which you might find useful. Some examples are fastutil, Trove and Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a `HashMap` uses 32 bytes per entry (12 bytes header + 16 bytes data + 4 bytes padding). It will also use 4 * the capacity bytes, so when it's all said and done a `HashMap` object will occupy

```
32 * size + 4 * capacity bytes
```

An `ArrayList` on the other hand generally allocates 4-8 bytes per entry. This can be more however, if you allocate a bigger capacity of the `ArrayList`, and only hold a few elements.